# ios11 webview html canvas content got cleared by page scroll

Tags: canvas, webview, ios11

The html page I made by using canvas becomes different in ios11!

When first show in the webview, the page looks fine, but, when it scrolls down and the canvas in it becomes invisible in the viewport, the content in the canvas disappears and never comes back when the page scroll back to top.

Does somebody know how to fix this problem or I should just wait until apple fixes it later?

Comment: I'm getting similar issue, I have canvas with some drawings in it and in my case if I do Zoom in and then zoom out the html page disapears. I found out that if I remove this line of code canvas.getContext("2d"); then I can do zooming without any issues

Comment: @Xusan Thanks for the infomation, but if without canvas.getContext('2d'), how can I get my canvas drawing to work?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me. I noticed that if I toggle in Safari Web Inspector any properties of the canvas, it is rendered again. Another similar issue is reported on SO ([Cordova Webview canvas redering bug on recent iOS versions (10.3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832642/cordova-webview-canvas-redering-bug-on-recent-ios-versions-10-3-1)).

So my plan is to detect the scroll event on top and force a redraw of the DOM element. I decided to use scrollstop event since [scroll event is not well supported on mobile device](http://andyshora.com/mobile-scroll-event-problems.html). The touchmove event is working as well but it is not as good as scrollevent because it only occurs when the finger touches the screen.

```
$('#my-canvas').on({
    'scrollstop': function(e) {
        // e.scrollTop() doesn't work... so
        console.log($(window).scrollTop()); 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
           console.log("Redraw of the canvas");
           $('#my-canvas').hide().show(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Not convinced it is diamond code but it just works on iOS.

PS: The problem is maybe only existing for the legacy web view and not the WkWebView. But this last one is so challenging with a lot of different network'issues that i never was able to use it.

Comment: My temporary solution was just like your's, haven't found any better solution yet. Transform our app to WKWebview is so difficult and can't image how much problem we will meet. So far this problem could only go this far.